# Error creating a form via service in Symfony 2.3

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

I want to create a form via form factory through a service in Symfony 2.3, but I couldn't be able to reproduce it.

My services.yml looks like this:

```
user.form.myservice:
    factory_method: createNamed
    factory_service: form.factory
    class: Symfony\Component\Form\Form
    arguments: [my_form_type_name]
user.form.myservice.type:
    class: XxX\MyBundle\Form\Type\myEntityType
    arguments: [null]
    tags:
      - { name: form.type, alias: my_form_type_name }
```

This is my form type definition (myEntityType)

```
class MyEntityType extends AbstractType
{
    private $class;

    public function __construct($class = null)
    {
        $this->class = (isset($class)) ? $class : 'XxX\MyBundle\Entity\myEntity';
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('first_name', 'text')
            ->add('last_name', 'text');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => $this->class
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my_form_type_name';
    }
}
```

In my controller, when I try to create the form:

```
$formFactory = $this->container->get('user.form.myservice');
$myForm = $formFactory->createForm();
```

It says:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Form\Form::createForm() in ...\proj1\src\XxX\MyBundle\Controller\ProfileController.php line 134
```

Any help please??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you're not passing any arguments to the constructor of `MyEntityType`. You also used `createForm` method in a wrong way. It expects followigng arguments: `$type`, `$data = null`, array $options = array()`.

To get this thing work, you should specify `type`:

```
$form = $this->createForm($this->get('user.form.myservice'), new YourEntity());
```

Comment: The problem is that my controller doesn't implement the default Controller class, it implements the BaseController class. The method $this->createForm(...) doesnt exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your factory service `user.form.myservice` returned the `FormInterface` instance (`Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory::createNamed`) and your can call the method `createForm` from `Form` instance.

And your have a bad logic for creating form.
The factory method must be return an finished object for next working, but you want expected factory.

Factory for your example:

```
public function createForm()
{
  $form = $this->formFactory->createForm('....');
  return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally resolved the problem creating the form this via:

```
$myForm = $this->container->get('form.factory')->create(new myEntityType(), new myEntity());
```

Thanks for your help!